# Add QR code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery and working on how to add QR code in jquery.

I have the following jquery code

```
var streamFile = function(p) 
{
    uploadPath = p;
    $.prompt("<center><b>Enter the URL in stream apps</b> <br>" + p + "</center>", 
    {
        buttons : 
        {
            "OK" : true,
            "Cancel" : false
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

where variable `p` has file URL.

I have found few library to create qr code.
 [Click Here](http://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/)

My problem is how do i convert `p` into `QR code` and add it to jquery

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a custom jquery script for making the QR code - I use [this one](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-qrcode/). It is small and very simple to use, and MIT. Download the script, add it to the root dir, and add it to your head:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
```

Then make a `<div id="qrcode"></div>` for where the QR code will appear

Then, make your text, or in your case a link into a QR with this command:

```
 $('#qrcode').qrcode("The stuff you want converted")
```

In your case, it may be:

```
 #('#qrcode').qrcode(p)
```